# How do I get application output from a Qt Creator plugin?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm writing an plugin for Qt Creator that will use the application output for a secondary reason (real-time graphical display of data).  However, I've run into the problem of getting the application output.  I don't wish to steal the output completely, just duplicate it.  However, being able to filter what the debugger gets would be nice but not a requirement.

In case you are wondering, I'm trying to avoid modifying existing plugins so that any update to Qt Creator won't conflict and require patching for every single new version.

Answer (score 0):

Creator is a open source project and your contributions are welcome:-) So why don't you to ask for Creator to be changed? The fastest way to do that is to write a patch that implements the interfaces you want and then submit it via codereview.qt-project.org.

Adding another patch that actually uses those interfaces can help, as that makes it easier to judge whether that functionality is really needed or whether there is a better way to implement it.